# How to resolve AWS_ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi4

I have the below error when I follow tutorial from   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-dynamodb-GettingStarted-MoviesItemOps01.py.html

```
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awscrt/io.py", line 546, in _seek
        return self._stream.seek(offset, whence)
    ValueError: negative seek value -1244619032
    Treating Python exception as error 34(AWS_ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT)
```

Comment: Please add all relevant info to your question, no links to external sites.

Comment: its a genuine site by aws

Comment: That makes no difference. Your question should contain the information needed to answer it.